# StackExchange filters (tag sets) aren't updating and emails have stopped?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, tag-filters

Are the [filters (tag sets) proposed by StackExchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/) still active and returning *current* results from their queries?

The [filter "**Java on all sites**"](https://stackexchange.com/filters/224/java?sort=newest), for example, list the "newest" questions asked... 11 hours ago! (Even though you would find [Java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=50) a few minutes old on SO at any time of the day).

I tried:

- accessing that filter on different computers (behind proxy or not), on different browsers (FireFox 3, 4, 5 ; Chrome, ...).
- clearing my cache, logging out from SE and logging back in.
- checking out [other](https://stackexchange.com/filters/219/eclipse-scala?sort=newest) [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/220/vcs?sort=newest) (and made them tried to other non-SO users, colleagues of mine, on their own browser).

All those filters seems "frozen" a few hours back and don't get updated anymore.
(It was working OK most of yesterday, but starting to not being updated at the end of yesterday GMT time)

Are other users seeing the same issue here?

Comment: the appropriate folks have been queried, but they have this terrible habit of sleeping occasionally; I'm sure all will be rectified.

Comment: @Marc: Tsss... Am I sleeping? Are you? Oh wait... it is 8:30 or 9:30 AM here ;) Never mind. I just wanted to know is didn't work just for me or if it was a more general issue. Thank you for having escalated this issue :)

Comment: Sleep is just an inefficient replacement for caffeine.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: State College, Pennsylvania? But it's like 3:40 AM there ?! Go to sleep already ;)

Comment: I have final edits due on my dissertation today at 10am. (Clearly why I'm wasting time here).  I won't be sleeping anytime soon.  :O)

Comment: @VonC: Just to confirm - yes, my filter stopped updating as well. The 2011-07-07 changes must have broken something.

Comment: @Marc  I am having the same problem.

Comment: And now Coding Horror Archives seems to be gone.

Comment: @Wladimir actually, in the end it wasn't the changes but *the build itself* - a tiny snowflake that somehow landed in exactly the one place that would depress the button marked "detonate".

Comment: Coding Horror Archives is back, SE seems well, but what is going on with the at sign in comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service responsible for aggregating network activity stopped working last night. We fixed the bug, and it's up an running again now, so filter emails are going out again. (Sorry about the duplicate emails some of you may have received as we were recovering -- we'll try to avoid that in the event of future outages.)

Comment: Yay, it works! I can see again :) Thank you.

Comment: Is it broken again? I got one email right when you mentioned it was fixed but I haven't gotten another one since even though I have them set for every 3 hours.

Comment: @OffBySome sorry, yea, there was still some minor brokenness, which is fixed now. You should have just received another filter email.

Answer (score 1):

They are working again.  I just got an email, and it looks like the email includes all the questions that were missed while they weren't being sent.