# Received five emails from my filter at once

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, email-notification

I just got flooded with five emails, each telling my that my filter on SE has 255 new questions available (it doesn't).

[image: Image of an email citing 255 new questions]

Comment: Maybe SE and you have different definitions of "new" :)

Comment: If you buy a used car it is new to *you* :)

Comment: Well, either SE changed its definition from yesterday, or traffic has increased by a factor of 100. :P

Comment: @Jeremy: I believe the previously reported issue with the tag filter not sending emails has been resolved, given what you're seeing.

Comment: What is this magnificent email client/RSS reader that you're using?

Comment: @yoda: [Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/), it's non-free ($10).

Comment: Thank you! Checking it out right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was due to a bug recovering from [StackExchange filters (tag sets) aren't updating and emails have stopped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97845/stackexchange-filters-tag-sets-arent-updating-and-emails-have-stopped).

That's been fixed so things should be proceeding as normal now.